# How to upload dynamoDb data dynamically on cloudsearch using only nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudsearch

AWS docs is one of the worst i ever seen. I'm seeking to Upload items from a dynamodb table but unfortunately i don't know how to "UploadDocuments" from a dynamodb table by using exclusively nodejs.

Is someone familiar with nodejs's cloudsearch api ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You can also trigger aws lambda fonctions on dynamodb event (streams) that support Node.js. For instance when something is added in the table your lambda fonction perform a specific code against other services. Unfortunately I'm not in touch with cloudsearch...

Comment: I created a domain in cloudsearch and uploaded a dynamodb document. All is fine. The problem is : The document is not static and new entries can be added to the dynamodb table, so i'm looking for a solution to update de document in cloudsearch everytime there is a new entry in dynamo. I don't want to make that manully in AWS console or the CLI each time a new entry is received. I want manage it automatically. I know lambda trigger dynamo events but before i really need to upload these docs in cloudsearch before processing any further things.

Comment: Have you had a look at the dynamodb streams? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html